# Stripe auth and capture

Tags: payment-gateway, stripe-payments

I am stuck with the question that I have successfully implemented **Instant Payment Method** of [Stripe](https://stripe.com/) Payment Gateway but now I want change the **Instant Payment** to **Two-Step Payments** method because of some requirement.

I'm refering [Does Stripe support auth and capture?](https://support.stripe.com/questions/does-stripe-support-authorize-and-capture). They are saying that

> Note that a charge must be captured within seven days or it will be cancelled.

but I want **Auto Capture Charge**  without Cancellation within 1 or 2 days if possible.

Help me if there is any idea to do this.

Your help would be appreciated.

Comment: Why do you need the deferred payment? Yes, it can be done.

Comment: How can be done that?

Comment: @KoradiyaMitul - have added answer

Answer (score 2):

https://stripe.com/docs/api#create_charge

`capture`
optional, default is true

> Whether or not to immediately capture the charge. When false, the charge issues an authorization (or pre-authorization), and will need to be captured later. Uncaptured charges expire in 7 days. For more information, see authorizing charges and settling later.

So, first off, you would create the charge, as you are now, but with `capture` set to false.

Then, when you want to actually charge the customer, you would call the [charge capture](https://stripe.com/docs/api#capture_charge) method, passing in the ID of the charge created in the above step.

**Unfortunately, there's no way of automatically doing this**, so you're going to need to write some code - maybe as a cron job or scheduled task to fire off the capture charge part in x number of days

Comment: is there a way to reverse the authorization after charge is captured or reverse the capture process in stripe?

Comment: @Yolanda i'm not sure, maybe refund is the only option there?

Comment: after checking you're right refund is the only option.

Comment: How to extend Uncaptured charges expiry time after 7 days?

Comment: @ashishbansal  You cannot.  That is a banking system requirement (which makes sense) between 2 and 7 days depending on payment vector.  You have to ask for a new authorization.